# rails3-jquery-autocomplete not working in Rails 3.2.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a *Post* and a *Tag* model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

  def tag!(tags)
    tags = tags.split(" ").map do |tag|
      Tag.find_or_create_by_name(tag)
    end
    self.tags << tags
  end
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end
```

schema:

```
  create_table "tags", :force => true do |t|
    t.string "name"
  end
```

part of `posts/_form`:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tags %>
    <%= text_field_tag :tags, params[:tags] %>
  </div>
```

I followed the [instructions](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete) in the git repository of the gem:

**controllers/posts_controller.rb:**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index]
  autocomplete :tags, :name
```

(etc..)

**routes.rb:**

```
resources :posts do
  get :autocomplete_tags_name, :on => :collection
end
```

All the JavaScripts files are there:

```
 <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/assets/autocomplete-rails.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but absolutely nothing happens (I tested this by adding a tag via console).

Any suggestions to make this gem work? (I'm on Rails 3.2.1)

Comment: Did you ever get your autocomplete search working? If yes please share your code. I am running into similar trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you could tidy up your pluralization (might work anyway but makes it easier to compare to the instructions)

**controllers/posts_controller.rb:**

```
autocomplete :tag, :name
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :posts do
    get :autocomplete_tag_name, :on => :collection
end
```

Then you need to change your text_field_tag into an autocomplete_field like it says under view in the instructions.

**From the instructions:**

```
form_for @product do |f|
    f.autocomplete_field :brand_name, autocomplete_brand_name_products_path
end
```

I suggest you use the Rails form helper form_for. In your case where you're using a partial it would look something like this:

**views/posts/new.html.erb (or wherever you call your partial from):**

```
form_for(:product, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| # I've found that @product doesn't work on new creations and therefor I use :product
    render(:partial => "form", :locals => {:f => f})
    f.submit
end
```

**views/posts/_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="fields">
    f.label :name, "Tag"
    f.autocomplete_field :tag_name, autocomplete_tag_name_products_path
</div>
```